# How to change custom post type position from backend

Tags: custom-post-types

I have registerd a post type called **Books** in function.php and this post type will display only for editor role. Now when i am login with my dummy editor i am seeing two post type one is Books and second Profile. I want to change default selected Books post type not profile.

What i want:
[My backed view](http://postimg.org/image/4q177kt6v/)

**My Code:**

```
function codex_custom_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => 'Books',
    'singular_name' => 'Book',
    'add_new' => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Book',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Book',
    'new_item' => 'New Book',
    'all_items' => 'All Books',
    'view_item' => 'View Book',
    'search_items' => 'Search Books',
    'not_found' =>  'No books found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No books found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Books'
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that when editors log in they should be automatically sent to the Books post type instead of going to the edit profile page?

I believe that by default for user roles that can't access the dashboard they default to the profile upon logging in. If you need to change this there is a plugin called [Peter's Login Redirect](http://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) that can handle this for you.

Once installed you can set up a redirect so that when editors log in they will be sent to whatever URL you set. Simply select the user role and then enter a URL. In your case the URL should be something like this:

/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=book

Comment: Hey bro thanks for giving such great idea, that plugin works for me. Once again thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting and saving the profile for the test editor?
Maybe once you've set up your profile it won't default any more.

Also, try setting `menu_position` to something like `5` instead of `null` (5 is the standard position in the hierarchy for Posts, so it will still appear above Profile)